# Can I use minimob advertise in my application?

Tags: android, ads

I recently went through minimob! for advertisements in android applications, I want to integrate this into my app , is this the good one? Can we trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is good. Yes you can trust it.

**Good points**:

- no cost
- wide location reach
- easy to integrate SDK
- exclusive to Android so far, so they've put some effort into this.

**Can you trust it**:

- Yes, having previously used it, i'd say it's trustworthy. Plus it complies Google Play Standards.

(No, i'm not employed by Minimob)

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but how to give payment details? i dint find any where in the website.

Comment: From what i remember, it's by mail. You'll have email them to check how to do it now.

Comment: sorry i dint understand your comment, they will mail me for asking details or should i send mail with all my details?

Comment: I said you should confirm with them about how their payment system works. I haven't used this in a while. Click on 'Contact us' at the bottom of their page.